# Bulk update parameter in jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

We have a lot of jobs that all perform SCM checkout based on a Build Parameter value: say `REPO_URL=ssh://url`. Over time there accumulated small differences in names and values of these parameters: `REPOURL`, `repo_url`, `=ssh://url/`, `=ssh://url:port`, etc.

We need to reduce them to a common denominator with a single parameter name and a single value. How do we bulk update parameters in 50+ jobs?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Jenkins Script Console](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-console/).

***NOTE:* these are essentially destructive operations, so make sure you tested your code on some spare jobs before running it in production!!!**

## Change default value of a parameter

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job)
// filter jobs by name if needed
.findAll { it.fullName.startsWith('sandbox/tmp-magic') }
.each {
  it
  .getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty)
  .getParameterDefinition('MAGIC_PARAMETER')
  // `each` ensures nothing happens if `get` returns null; also see paragraph below
  .each {
    it.defaultValue = 'shmagic'
  }
  // the job has changed, but next config reload (f.x. at restart) will overwrite our changes
  // so we need to save job config to its config.xml file
  it.save()
}
```

Instead of `.getParameterDefinition('MAGIC_PARAMETER')` you can use

```
.parameterDefinitions
.findAll { it.name == 'MAGIC_PARAMETER' }
```

, changing predicate in `findAll` if you need f.x. to change value of multiple parameters with different names - then you iterate over found definitions via `each{}`.

## Change parameter name (and value)

This is slightly more tricky, since apparently you cannot edit name of `ParameterDefinition`, only replace one in a list.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job)
.findAll { it.fullName.startsWith('sandbox/tmp-magic') }
.each {
  def parameters = it.getProperty(ParametersDefinitionProperty).parameterDefinitions
  def oldParameter = parameters.find { it.name == 'FOO' }
  // avoid changing jobs without this parameter
  if (!oldParameter)
    return
  def idx = parameters.indexOf(oldParameter)
  // preserve original value if necessary
  def oldValue = oldParameter.defaultValue
  parameters[idx] = new StringParameterDefinition('GOOD_FOO', oldValue)
  it.save()
}
```

## Bonus points: replace value for SCM step in Freestyle and Pipeline From SCM job

Some of our jobs use MercurialSCM plugin, and some use MultiSCM plugin to checkout multiple repos, so this is what I tested it with.

````
import hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.multiplescms.MultiSCM
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob

Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job)
.findAll { it.fullName.startsWith('sandbox/tmp-magic') }
.each {
  print "Checking $it ... "
  if (it.class == FreeStyleProject && it.scm) {
    println "Freestyle"
    it.scm = replaceWhateverScm(it.scm)
    it.save()
  } else if (it.class == WorkflowJob) {
    print "Pipeline ... "
    def flow = it.definition
    if (flow.class == CpsScmFlowDefinition) {
      println "ScmFlow"
      def scm = replaceWhateverScm(flow.scm)
      def newFlow = new CpsScmFlowDefinition(scm, flow.scriptPath)
      newFlow.lightweight = flow.lightweight
      it.definition = newFlow
      it.save()
    } else
      println "unsupported definition"
  } else
    println "unsupported job"
}

def replaceWhateverScm(scm) {
  if (scm.class == MercurialSCM) {
    println "replacing MercurialSCM"
    return replaceMercurialSource(scm)
  }
  if (scm.class == MultiSCM) {
    println "replacing MultiSCM"
    // cannot replace part of MultiSCM, replace whole scm instead
    return new MultiSCM(
      scm.configuredSCMs
      .collect { (it.class == MercurialSCM) ? replaceMercurialSource(it) : it }
    )
  }
  throw new Exception("unknown class ${scm.class}")
}

def replaceMercurialSource(MercurialSCM original) {
  if (!original.source.toLowerCase().contains('repo_url'))
    return original
  def s = new MercurialSCM('<new_url>')
  for (v in ["browser","clean","credentialsId","disableChangeLog","installation","modules","revision","revisionType","subdir",]) {
    s."$v" = original."$v"
  }
  return s
}```
````